# How to cast a dynamic array to a list in Cython?

Tags: python, c, cython

I'm implementing a simple Eratosthenes sieve. It's fairly straightforward when I make a constant-sized stack array for the results, but this approach will restrict the numbers of primes that I can calculate.

So I tried using some dynamic heap array; the issue here is that, in the "cpdef" function, I want to return a python list and I must cast the array to a list, but that's not possible.

If I do it without dereferencing, Cython will complain about "*Python objects cannot be cast from pointers of primitive types*" and, if I dereference the array, it will return the first element, which is no surprise.

I'm aware of NumPy or using some list comprehension, **but I don't want to <s>lower the performance</s> or use third-party packages**.

What is the fastest way for doing so, considering limitations? CPython arrays are slow: Maybe typed memoryview? And why is it that Cython cannot cast dynamic arrays?

```
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from libc.math cimport sqrt
from cython.operator cimport dereference

cdef inline int is_prime(unsigned int num, unsigned int *primes, unsigned int counter):
    cdef unsigned int i
    for i in range(counter):
        if num % primes[i] == 0:
            return 0
        if primes[i] > <unsigned int> sqrt(num) + 1:
            break
    return 1


cpdef list primes_below(unsigned int x):

    # cdef:
    #    unsigned int primes[1_000_000]
    #    unsigned int counter = 0
    #    unsigned int i
    #
    # for i in range(2, x):
    #    if is_prime(i, primes, counter):
    #        primes[counter] = i
    #        counter += 1

    # return (<list> primes)[:counter]

    
    # Alternative approach: (It doesn't work!)
    
    cdef:
        unsigned int *primes = <unsigned int *> malloc(sizeof(int) * x)
        unsigned int counter = 0
        unsigned int i
        
    for i in range(2, x):
        if is_prime(i, primes, counter):
            primes[counter] = i
            counter += 1

    return <list> primes
    # return <list> dereference(primes)
```

P.S.: I'm a C newbie, so I may be missing some subtle details.

---

**EDIT:**
First, I should thank @DavidW for his endless comprehensive answers to Cython questions. Second, he was right!

> **List comprehensions are really fast**

In contradiction to what I was thinking.

This is the new implementation:

```
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False
# cython: cdivision=True

from cython.view cimport array as cy_array
from libc.math cimport sqrt

cdef inline int is_prime(unsigned int num, unsigned int[::1] primes, unsigned int counter):
    cdef unsigned int i
    for i in range(counter):
        if num % primes[i] == 0:
            return 0
        if primes[i] > <unsigned int> sqrt(num) + 1:
            break
    return 1


cpdef list primes_below(unsigned int x):
    cdef:
        unsigned int[::1] primes = cy_array(shape=(x,), itemsize=sizeof(int), format="I")
        unsigned int counter = 0
        unsigned int i
        
    for i in range(2, x):
        if is_prime(i, primes, counter):
            primes[counter] = i
            counter += 1

    return [primes[i] for i in range(counter)]
```

I find Cython arrays to be fast and straightforward, **so allocating memory with `malloc` is overkill.**

Answer (score 0):

> And why Cython cannot cast dynamic arrays?

How could it? It doesn't know how long your array is. All it knows is that that it's a pointer to some bit of memory that should be interpreted as ints. Even if it were clever enough to look at `malloc` that wouldn't help - you actually fill less memory up.

> I'm aware of NumPy or using some list comprehension, but I don't want to lower the performance or use third-party packages. What is the fastest way for doing so, considering limitations? CPython arrays are slow;

Have you actually measured any of these performance claims you're making? Allocating an `array.array` is slightly slower than using `malloc` but access into it is very quick (using a memoryview).

Since you have to copy into a list at the end anyway, why not just append to a list as you go and skip the "fast" C array? It might well be quicker than copying at the end.

> `unsigned int *primes = <unsigned int *> malloc(sizeof(int) * x)`
>
> [...]
>
> P.S: I'm a C newbie; so take it easy on me. Thanks! :)

Memory leak here - the memory you `malloc`ed is never `free`d. The big advantage of using Python containers is that you *don't have to consider C memory allocation*.

---

To actually answer your question: The easiest thing is probably to create a temporary Cython memoryview of the array and then pass that to `list`:

```
return list(<unsigned int[:counter:1]>primes)
```

Comment: Thanks, @DavidW. Actually, I've tested three different ideas. Set primes to be a C heap array, list, and array.array (no memoryview). It takes 1x, 8x, and 12x. Now I'm defining primes by `unsigned int[:] primes = <unsigned int[:x] *> malloc(sizeof(int) * x)` and returning `list(primes[:counter])` which is pretty fast. Based on this solution, I've got 3 questions: 1) Is there any other implementation that is significantly faster? 2) Should (and if yes, how) I free the allocated memory? 3) why returning `<list> (primes[:counter])` raise an error? Isn't that supposed to be the same as `list(...)`

Comment: Your result with depend on the size but for me `array.array` with memoryview is similar to `malloc` (because you don't have to waste time converting at the end). `array.array` without memoryview is slow though. Questions: 1) I'd try a list comprehension - Cython can often optimize those pretty well; 2) You should definitely free it. The usual way is a `try` block with `free(pointer)` in `finally`. 3) It isn't really the same - `<list>` relies on Cython having some hard-coded cast logic,  while `list(...)` is a Python function call.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidW. I saw your answers to Cython questions, and It's jaw-dropping! It's literally endless. You should seriously consider writing a book about Cython! There is a book, and it's a good one, but I would love to read another with new and more examples and explanations! I'd change the question to mention that you were right, and list comprehensions are indeed fast. I was looking at them as a sort of slow python syntaxes that we must avoid for sake of performance, my last question is where should I use <list> instead of list()? Thanks. :)

Comment: "where should I use <list> instead of list()" - pretty rarely I think. I think conversions to/from some C++ containers might be supported, but that's largely it